# Get the latest updated value based on other columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

`I have an example like this

```
name1               name2                  name3
Acer laurinum        NA                     Acer laurinum
NA                   Acer laurinum Hassk.   Acer laurinum Hassk.
Acmella paniculata   NA                     Acmella paniculata
Aglaia lawii         NA                     Aglaia lawii
NA                   Aglaia lawii (Wight)   Aglaia lawii (Wight)
```

I would like to find a way to add the author part for same species here i.e. `Hassk` (2nd row) should be added to the first row using `tidyverse`. One solution is that I am thinking is to use `str_detect` searching for same strings then add the author part, but I cant get it done.

One way I did before was to create a separate vector for only names associated with authors. Then for each row I used `lapply` by saying that if we have 2 names being the same i.e. `Acer laurinum`, then the other one should be replaced by the name with author i.e. `Acer laurinum Hassk`.

Any suggestions by using `tidyverse`?

Code for example table.

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("Acer laurinum", NA, "Acmella paniculata", "Aglaia lawii", NA),
                 name2 = c(NA, "Acer laurinum Hassk.", NA, NA, "Aglaia lawii (Wight)"),
                 name3 = c("Acer laurinum", "Acer laurinum Hassk.", "Acmella paniculata", "Aglaia lawii", "Aglaia lawii (Wight)"))
```

Desired output

```
name1               name2                  name3
Acer laurinum        NA                     Acer laurinum Hassk.
NA                   Acer laurinum Hassk.   Acer laurinum Hassk.
Acmella paniculata   NA                     Acmella paniculata
Aglaia lawii         NA                     Aglaia lawii (Wight)
NA                   Aglaia lawii (Wight)   Aglaia lawii (Wight)
```

Honestly, this is a combination of 2 different dataframes. One dataframe has several NA values in name1, and the other has several NA values in name2. I used  `bind_rows` to get the final table. And column name3 would be my final column

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
df$name4 <- paste(df$name1,df$name2) %>% 
  str_remove("NA") %>% 
  str_trim()
```

The output:

```
               name1                name2                name3                name4
1      Acer laurinum                 <NA>        Acer laurinum        Acer laurinum
2               <NA> Acer laurinum Hassk. Acer laurinum Hassk. Acer laurinum Hassk.
3 Acmella paniculata                 <NA>   Acmella paniculata   Acmella paniculata
4       Aglaia lawii                 <NA>         Aglaia lawii         Aglaia lawii
5               <NA> Aglaia lawii (Wight) Aglaia lawii (Wight) Aglaia lawii (Wight)
```

**EDIT**

It is just needed to add a `walk`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df$name4 <- paste(df$name1,df$name2) %>%
  str_remove("NA") %>%
  str_trim()

walk(2:nrow(df), 
     ~ if (str_detect(df$name4[.x],df$name4[.x-1]))
       df$name4[.x-1] <<- df$name4[.x])
```

The output:

```
               name1                name2                name3                name4
1      Acer laurinum                 <NA>        Acer laurinum Acer laurinum Hassk.
2               <NA> Acer laurinum Hassk. Acer laurinum Hassk. Acer laurinum Hassk.
3 Acmella paniculata                 <NA>   Acmella paniculata   Acmella paniculata
4       Aglaia lawii                 <NA>         Aglaia lawii Aglaia lawii (Wight)
5               <NA> Aglaia lawii (Wight) Aglaia lawii (Wight) Aglaia lawii (Wight)
```

Comment: I afraid not the output column must contain all possible names with authors. i.e. Acer laurinum Hassk. see my output.

Comment: My mistake, @Anh! Please, see the edited solution that I have just posted.

Comment: Hi it worked well with my example, but not with my data :(. I just realized that you taking the second row then find the name right.

Comment: Well, maybe you would like to add an example where my code fails.

Comment: should I create a discussion room?

Comment: It would be best if you could provide a representative example of your data.

Comment: Yes, I did create a new one

Comment: Just post it then!